# Image Base64 url string to bytearray

Tags: c#, arrays, image, url, base64

In my application I use rich editor. In this editor, when I add image it returns base64 url string . My problem is some images has too long base64 string so it cant change to byte array. How can I solve this problem. Code I wrote is below.

```
if (url.Contains("data:"))
            {
                int j = url.IndexOf(';');
                contentType = url.Substring(5, j-5);
                int i = url.IndexOf(',');
                url = url.Substring(i+1);


                data=Convert.FromBase64String(url);


            }
```

Comment: Can you give an example of a string which causes a crash?